# Location target permission 23

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I'm using altbeacon library to monitor and range beacons. I've read your requesting permission page and just want to know, if I target location permission for API 23+ (), will scan works on devices with API < 23? I don't have real device, so can't test it. Or is there any way to not request location permission with device with API below 23? Thanks for your answers

Comment: Why don't you use a virtual device to do the test ? All API are available. Just for info, the API 23 made a huge change in permission, from there, the permission should be check at run time, prior that, this use the manifest so no reason to block there.

Comment: virtual device can't use Bluetooth, it's necessary to scan beacons.

Comment: My bad, but the rest of the comment still stand. You need to manage the permission differently for prior 23 and the rest.

Comment: yes, I do, but my question is if I will be able to scan beacons on devices with API < 23 if I'm using location service only on devices with API >= 23

Comment: And again, if you manage your permission correctly, yes (unless the API doesn't support those API). The change is only for newer API (23 +), for the rest, the code will be skipped (well your condition should do that) and it will work. Basicly, you just need to use a false bluetooth data to test if this will work and same for location in a AVD to be sure, no need to test with a real beacon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restating the core question:

If you build an app that has a **minSdkVersion < 23 but the targetSdkVersion >= 23**, **what happens when you try to scan for bluetooth beacons?**

**Short answer: it works.**

Longer answer:

- **The user permissions request won't happen.**  with a minSdkVersion < 23, The compiler will stop you from including a line of code like `requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);`   because it won't run on earlier Android versions.  If you wrap it in an if statement like `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)` it won't get executed. If you add annotations like `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` the app will crash when trying to execute the code.
- **The beacon scanning will just work**, both in the foreground and the background, regardless of the fact that the user permissions have not been granted.  Earlier Android versions can't request the permission from the user, so the app just behaves as if they have been granted.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 23 and on, you need to check if the app has been granted a "dangerous" permission and if not ask the user.
The Android support library has helper functions for this.
See [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).
The main functions are `checkSelfPermission` and `requestPermissions`.
In order not to have problems with older versions of Android you can use the following to check if you are on a device running Marshmallow or not:

```
public static boolean isMNC() {     
   return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
}
```

This will return `true` if you are on a device running Marshmallow or newer, `false` otherwise. So, if this returns `true`, check for the permission, otherwise don't.
You should probably also use the annotation `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` on the function where you call the `checkSelfPermission` and `requestPermissions`.

Comment: based on: [link](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html) I don't know if the library will perform scan beacons if the permission is only for API 23+..that's what I'm asking for :D

Comment: Looking on the AndroidManifest of the Android Beacon Library 2.9.1, it uses the following to include the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission:

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

That means the permission is requested only on devices with api 23 and above, so it is not needed on lower apis. So, it should work ok. This might help you also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988149/altbeacon-library-background-service/35988619#35988619